# Javascript push() method not working aside jQuery inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I am trying to add values to a simple array, but I can't get the values pushed into the array.

So far so good, this is the code I have:

```
codeList = [];

jQuery('a').live(
    'click', 
    function()
    {
         var code = jQuery(this).attr('id');
         if( !jQuery.inArray( code, codeList ) ) {
              codeList.push( code );
              // some specific operation in the application
         }   
    }
);
```

The above code doesn't work!
But if I manually pass the value:

```
codeList = [];

jQuery('a').live(
    'click', 
    function()
    {
         var code = '123456-001'; // CHANGES HERE
         if( !jQuery.inArray( code, codeList ) ) {
              codeList.push( code );
              // some specific operation in the application
         }   
    }
);
```

It works!

I can't figure out what's going on here, because if I do other tests manually it also work!

Comment: Include the HTML. I am quite sure that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Starting an ID with a digit is invalid if you're using XHTML or a doctype prior to HTML5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this .. Instead of cheking for bool check for its index..
It returns a -1 when it is not found..

```
var codeList = [];

jQuery('a').live(
    'click', 
    function()
    {
         var code = '123456-001'; // CHANGES HERE
         if( jQuery.inArray( code, codeList ) < 0) { // -ve Index means not in Array
              codeList.push( code );
              // some specific operation in the application
         }   
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns `-1` when the value is not found, also `.live` is deprecated on jQuery 1.7+ and you're missing a `var` statement in your `codeList` declaration. Here's a rewrite of your code:

```
//without `var`, codeList becomes a property of the window object
var codeList = [];

//attach the handler to a closer ancestor preferably
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    //no need for attributes if your ID is valid, use the element's property
    var code = this.id;
    if ($.inArray(code, codeList) === -1) { //not in array
        codeList.push(code);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VagEv/)

And as I stated in the question comments, IDs starting with a digit are illegal unless you're using the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: I am not using var because it is a global variable

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino Declare it in the global context then. It's good practice to use the `var` keyword even then. Without any `var` statement, your code won't pass JSHint/Lint, generate errors in strict mode and `codeList` will be created as a property of window object without the DontDelete attribute flag.

Comment: Of course, if you already have it declared in the global context with a `var` statement, ignore the comment above.